# Why do I show up twice?

Tags: support, status-completed

It looks like my account from SharePoint Overflow was moved over, and when I logged into sharepoint.stackexchange.com, it created a new account for me.  Both use the same gmail openID login, have the same picture, etc. Is it possible to merge me with myself?  :)

Answer (score 1):

I have merged your accounts.  Enjoy!